# Build multiple Docker images with gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to configure a `gitlab-ci.yml` file to automatically build two Docker images. I've seen it being done with docker-compose, but in my case I don't want to use docker-compose.

The `docker-compose.yml` configuration that I've seen is something like this:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  vcxagency-base:
    build:
      context: https://github.com/AbsaOSS/vcxagencynode.git#master
      dockerfile: ./vcxagency-base/vcxagency-base.Dockerfile
    image: vcxagency-base:1.15.0
  
  vcxagency-node:
    build:
      context: https://github.com/AbsaOSS/vcxagencynode.git#master
      dockerfile: ./vcxagency-node/Dockerfile
    image: vcxagency-node:0.3.1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOG_LEVEL=debug
      - LOG_ENABLE_INDYSDK=false
      - LOG_JSON_TO_CONSOLE=false
      - SERVER_PORT=8080
      - SERVER_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_KB=300
      - SERVER_ENABLE_TLS=false
```

I haven't really worked with Docker at all. I tried to explore the documentation, but couldn't find something specific.

The goal would be to have these running on a Kubernetes cluster, but for now I just want to build the images in GitLab.

Comment: Hi there! Does the answer I provided below help you with your initial problem? If so, you might wanna accept it in order to help other people that run into similar issues with their pipeline. Maybe provide further info if the post doesn’t answer your problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make use of Kaniko as a docker build tool and GitLabs feature called matrix builds.

**How to use kaniko for building docker images**

Snippet below is taken from the official GitLab [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html#building-a-docker-image-with-kaniko)

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"${CI_REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${CI_REGISTRY_USER}" "${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - >-
      /kaniko/executor
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/Dockerfile"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
```

**What are matrix builds?**

GitLab introduced a feature for parallel job executions which is called matrix jobs, basically the job is executed multiple times with different sets of variables (variable matrix).

Taking the above snippet as a base you would result in something like below (suppose your dockerfiles are stored under `<PROJECT_DIR>/dockerfiles/` and are named `A.dockerfile` and `B.dockerfile`, respectively):

```yaml
.kaniko-build:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - mkdir -p /kaniko/.docker
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"${CI_REGISTRY}\":{\"auth\":\"$(printf "%s:%s" "${CI_REGISTRY_USER}" "${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - >-
      /kaniko/executor
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/${DOCKERFILE}"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_COMMIT_TAG}"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG

docker-build:
  extends: .build
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - DOCKERFILE: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/dockerfiles/A.dockerfile
      - DOCKERFILE: ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/dockerfiles/B.dockerfile
```

Comment: This is the way to go. I simplified the example from doc & turned into clonable repo:
https://how-to.dev/how-to-build-docker-images-in-gitlab-ci